Camel 4 XML DSL how to import routes defined in separate XML
I have multiple routes and different conditions put up in a single route xml file.Want to clean up this route XML as below.

Main route XML contains the common route (be it validation and other request transformation/lookup )

In the main route include different product routes, each of the product route evaluates a field in request and proceeds to its route execution if condition matches.


Currently using Camel 4. When I tried some sample referencing below it fails with error.
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://XXXXX
https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red_hat_integration/2023.q2/apache-camel-3.18-doc/manual/faq/how-do-i-import-routes-from-other-xml-files.html#:~:text=xml%20which%20contains%20a%20couple,shown%20below%20in%20this%20example.
is this something possible in camel 4? and help me with approaches for achieving this.
